# Is there a dataset with the MGRS 100Km square id for every such square on world map?

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I'm trying to compile a list of MGRS 100km square identifiers for every such square (eg 4QFJ for Honolulu Hawaii); excluding the poles (85 to -85 latitudes).

Does anyone know of a dataset or can point me in a good direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download selected squares from [Military Grid Reference System (MGRS): Downloads](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/grids/mgrs_100km_dloads.html), or get a large grid file from [GIS MGRS Grid Data layers in GIS Format](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/coordsys/gislayers/gislayers.html).

These are likely to be free of copyright, since they are US Government publications.